# Preventing Local Access to IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, permissions

I have a PC that is used as a server, its OS is Win2008 R2 and the application is developed by ASP.NET 2012 and C#. The server is dedicated to my application and is placed in the user location. Since I can't physically protect unauthorized access to server I'm looking for a suitable method to preventing another person has access to files on the server. I know I can set login password but the HDD can be remove and install on another PC. Is there any way that only IIS Server has permission to access data? (Or any other reliable solution)

Thank in advance,
Reza

Comment: If someone can get physical access to the machine, most other issues are moot. But: an encrypted file-system and ACLs on the important drive locations would go at least some way to making it *inconvenient* for an attacker...

Comment: If you want only this IIS box has access to the files, you might encrypt the disk using BitLocker or another encryption product.

Comment: @ Marc Gravell:   I encrypted root folder but get an error message when requesting page from web browser: "401 - unauthorized access is denied due to invalid credentials"

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can set access to your root folder to only IIS_IUSERS.also you can modify read/write access.[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work as IIS_IUSRS on different machines should have the same SID. Then the protection you describe won't stop the files from being read after moving the disk to another Windows machine.